# Sharepoint create a view for the month of april and march in a list

Tags: sharepoint-server, view, sharepoint-list-filter

we need to know how many items are there for the due date column (DueDate) for the  month april and march

how do we setup a view which shows the number of items for each month ?

any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a calculated column which with formula as "MONTH([Due Date])". And data type select "Number".

Then filter the list view as calculated column equal to 3(for march) or 4(for April).

[image]

And in the Totals section, select Count for Due Date column (Mine is Modified column):

[image]

The count will return under the header:

[image]

Comment: great the solution i was looking for .